# Transaction unconfirmed - day 12!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I've got a transaction from 2017-12-06 that's still unconfirmed - i really need this money now as ive moved house - how can i get this sorted - I am will to pay for help at this point.

Can anyone please help?? Tim.

https://blockchain.info/tx/44c784d8f82d962103ffdf5d463a1460150a21cc67a0750d4a3f6a35a0d18d9a

Comment: I'm in the same situation. If this info is correct your coins should return in two days:  #9312 a72f76c Increase mempool expiry time to 2 weeks (morcos) https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.14.0.md

Comment: thanks .... once returned, should i then ry with a higher fee? whats a good fee to make this happen quickly?

Comment: 2 weeks have past, still nothing, can anybody advise? tried the zap wallet thing, and its just removed the transactions, so theres nothing in my wallet on my mac. the only thing i have to go on is the bitcoin link

can anybody help me, am desperate now to get this money - need it for a house move.

Comment: Now that you've done the zap wallet thing do `bitcoind -rescan` and the coins should show in your wallet.

Comment: @hermancain  you are the mother f&^king man - sorted it with that command! killed the old transaction and made a new one with a better fee, now i understand all that bit! thank you soo much dude!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is another duplicate and already answered here by dooode:
[Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/11928)

You have to stop/reverse the old Bitcoin transaction you created without confirmations:
Make a backup of your wallet.dat

Run `bitcoind` or `bitcoin-qt` with `-zapwallettxes=1` option.

This makes the wallet "forget" any unconfirmed transactions, thus enabling you to reuse their inputs.
Create a new transaction to make your payment and add an appropriate fee this time.

You can now send the bitcoins where ever you want or you can send them all back to yourself.